# JUnit test for Constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I need to write unit tests for this constructor, I have written one unit test for the case when BufferedImage image is null:

```
@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testConstructorNull(){        
    bfImage = null;
    ColorImage cImage = null;
    assertNotNull(cImage = new ColorImage(bfImage));
}
```

, but I am not sure how to write a test when everything works

```
public ColorImage(BufferedImage image)
{
    super(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), TYPE_INT_RGB);
    int width = image.getWidth();
    int height = image.getHeight();
    for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
        for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
            setRGB(x, y, image.getRGB(x,y));
}
```

Please help.

Comment: A constructor never returns a null instance.

Comment: A constructor should always succeed or fail with an exception. As Andy said, it cannot return `null` in Java.

Comment: That's right, but I think the point here is that he's testing for `NullPointerException`, not that he's expecting the returned value to be `null`...

Comment: Also, just as another FYI, you should not do an assert on the same line (or after) a method call you are expecting to throw an exception. In the above case, `assertNotNull` is never called because `new ColorImage` throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a mock library ([EasyMock](http://easymock.org), [Mockito](http://site.mockito.org/) or the like), or else you simply extend `BufferedImage` to make it return some expected value and/or verify the correct calls are performed, for example:

```
public class MockBufferedImage extends BufferedImage {

    private int calledGetWidth, calledGetHeight;
    private int calledGetRGB;

    public MockBufferedImage() {
        super(10, 10, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    }

    @Override
    public int getWidth() {
        calledGetWidth++;
        return super.getWidth();
    }

    @Override
    public int getHeight() {
        calledGetHeight++;
        return super.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRGB(int x, int y) {
        calledGetRGB++;
        return 0xff00ff;
    }

    // An example method verifier, just for show!
    public void verifyCalled(int times) {
        assertThat(calledGetWidth, is(times));
        assertThat(calledGetHeight, is(times));
        assertThat(calledGetRGB, is(times * 100));
    }
}
```

You can then pass an instance of the `MockBufferedImage` to the constructor and afterwards check that indeed your constructed object has correct values for `width`, `height` and `RGB`.

You can additionally add some behavior verifying methods (like `verifyCalled` in the example) to check if all operations where carried out as expected (number of times called, execution order...).

Comment: I have a predefined class:

Comment: public class ColorImage extends BufferedImage
{
    /**
     * Create a ColorImage copied from a BufferedImage
     * Convert to 24-bit direct colour
     * @param image The image to copy
     */
    public ColorImage(BufferedImage image)
    {
        super(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), TYPE_INT_RGB);
        int width = image.getWidth();
        int height = image.getHeight();
        for (int y=0; y<height; y++)
            for (int x=0; x<width; x++)
                setRGB(x, y, image.getRGB(x,y));
    }

Comment: which I cannot change, I've already written test for its methods, but when I asked the tutor, he told me to write tests for the constructor as well, so I cannot change the original class

Comment: I would remove the verify method, because if the newly created ColorImage has the right values (width, height, etc.) then you already know the methods have been called (where else should the values come from?).

Comment: @Florian: I agree, that's what I call the "Mockito way"... let's see if you like my next edit

Comment: @V.Savage: you don't need to change the `ColorImage` class, the presented class is just a **mock** for a `BufferedImage`. You pass it to your class's constructor in order to later verify your constructor's behavior! I know it sounds weird: you define a fake `BufferedImage` just for test, so you can demonstrate that `ColorImage`'s constructor called the right methods...

Comment: @Marco: Personally, I always prefer assert over verify, but in this case, you are just re-inventing the mockito verify method... I would keep the asserts in the test class in any case.

Comment: So you would drop the `verifyCalls` method altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Just check that the created instance is in the expected state.

What this means is up to you to decide. It looks you set some pixels to values, maybe those can be used in an assertion to check that certain pixel really got set apropriately.

Note that this not only tests the constructor, but also the setRGB and the assumed acsessor. This is actually a nice thing for a test, because it avoids testing internal state that we want to hide from the outside by using classes in the first place.

Comment: ColorImage cImage = new ColorImage(bfImage);
assertEquals("Constuctor does not work properly", image, cImage);

Comment: So I tried to create another ColorImage class and pass to it the same buffer, but I get back an error